# FineUploader client / server code locations

Tags: cors, fine-uploader

Does the signature endpoint need to reside on the same physical server as the client code? 
For example, I want client.html to reside on apache webserver web.acme.com. The servlet for signing to reside on tomcat.acme.com.

Is this an acceptable configuration?

j

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about support for [cross-origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  Fine Uploader has supported this since version 3.3.  The [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/CORS.html) outlines what you must do to properly account for a cross-origin environment, such as yours.  Your server will need to be coded to properly follow the CORS specification, and this can get a bit tricky in IE9 and older.  There is a PHP example in the Fine Uploader Server repository on Github that includes a fully-functional cross-origin aware server for Fine Uploader S3.  If I remember correctly, you are using Java, and there is not CORS-aware Java example yet.

To get everything working in your cross-origin environment for Fine Uploader S3, you will first need to set the `expected` property of the [`cors` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#cors-option) to `true`.  Server-side, you will need to handle an OPTIONS (preflight) request, and return proper CORS headers in your OPTIONS and POST responses.  If you are using the [delete file feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#deletefile-option_1) in a cross-origin environment, you will also need to override the default `method` property of the `deleteFile` option to "post" if you need to support IE9 and older (note that the `allowXdr` property defaults to `true` in Fine Uploader S3).

I wrote a [blog post on CORS support](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/) when it was pushed out with Fine Uploader 3.3.  You can apply the same concepts to Fine Uploader S3.  You can also take a look at the [Fine Uploader S3 PHP CORS example](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-cors.php) that handles all features in a cross-origin environment.  In fact, the [live S3 demo on the home page](http://fineuploader.com/#s3-demo) uses that exact PHP code on the backend as the server portion and the page are hosted on different domains.

Comment: Josh - I'm afraid I won't have time for that any time soon.  CORS is an advanced topic, and if you are dealing with a cross-origin environment, you will have to spend some time familiarizing yourself with the associated concepts.  Fine Uploader S3 isolates you from almost all of the CORS-related nastiness when dealing directly with AWS, but if your signature or uploadSuccess endpoints are cross-origin, you are forced to deal with this at least in your server code.  Take a look at the PHP example I linked to, it will serve as a good model.

Comment: Note that the complexity of your server-side code varies depending on your requirements.  A fairly simple implementation is all that is required if you don't want to support IE9 and older.  If you do, then things get a bit tricky.  The PHP S3 CORS example handles all of that though.  It's heavily commented as well.  If you are not at all familiar with CORS, you should read the first link in my answer, which is a good overview of the concepts.